# broadcasting signed transaction from multiple endpoints

Tags: raw-transaction

I want my transaction to broadcast fast to network.
Will it help if I broadcast it from multiple publick APIs?
etherscan.io/pushTX
+ 
MyEtherWalet

Will it help transaction to be included in nearest possible block?

Answer (score 1):

It may help, but the multiple endpoints could already be connected (peers), hence sharing the same transaction pool. In that case, almost nothing changes. But it cannot hurt; since the nonces will be the same, double spending is not an issue.

For faster mining, another option is to increase the gas price.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you mean, but it seems to me that if you do transactions from more than one end point they are all separate transaction and you pay multiple times.

If this is not what you mean, then maybe you can give some clarification.